# Prolog return date and event associated with it

Tags: prolog

So hello guys,  i have been working on this question for hours, but i can solve it, if you guys can give me hints that would be great! 
The problem is long but i believe from what I can see that the solution won't be more than 5 lines.

So I'm given a bunch of Data, lets say:

```
day(1,1, 'New Year')
day(2,1, 'The day after the new year')
day(23,1, 'The day i will finally understand this language :)')
day(14,2, 'Valentin's day')
day(16,2, 'Family day')
day(22,2, 'hein.. dont now lol')
```

So the first number is the day, second month and third event, and 
so on for the other months. each month also have a number a days:

```
nday(1,31).
nday(2,28).
nday(3,31).
nday(4,30).
nday(5,31).
```

If i enter DayofTheMonth(1,L), such that L is a List and 1 January, 
i should return a list with all the days in that month and the events as well .
In this case it should be: `[(1,'New year', (2,'The day after the new year'),
(23, 'The day i will finally understand this language :)')]`.  this is what i did: (i don't even know the basic case smh) I'm so sorry i know 
this solution is wrong it doesn't even handle days that don't have event, 
but i just don't know where to go, i just feed a feedback or something

```
dayoftheMonth(X, L):- nday(X,Answer), 
                  dayMonth(X, Answer, L).
dayMonth(X,Y,[_|B]):- 
    X=<Y,
    day(Day, X, Event),
    W is Day + 1,
    dayMonth(X,W,[(Day,Event)|B]).
```

Comment: I don't even talk about the predicat that should return the days with no event :((

Comment: are multiple events on the same day allowed?

Comment: Dont think so, for instance new year can only be for 1 day, same for valentine

Comment: I mean can Januay 1st be both a birthday and new year. So two events, but on the very same day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the predicate [`findall/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3) for that. The predicate has three arguments:

- The `template`, the format of the output
- The `goal`, the predicate you call that should be matched
- The `bag`, the returning list of predicates.

So `dayofTheMonth` simply reads:

```
dayofTheMonth(Month,List) :-
    findall((Day,Event),day(Month,Day,Event),List).
```

---

If you want to solve it without a `findall`, you can solve it by iterating over all the days until the number of days. The **basecase** is thus when the **day** has passed the number of days of the month.

```
dayofTheMonth(Month,Day,[]) :-
    nday(Month,Threshold),
    Day > Threshold,
    !.
```

The inductive case always looks if there is an event planned that day, if so, you put it as head of the list and append it with the events on the next day, if there is no such event, the resulting list is the list of the next days. So:

```
dayofTheMonth(Month,Day,[(Day,Event)|T]) :-
    day(Day,Month,Event),
    !,
    Day1 is Day+1,
    dayofTheMonth(Month,Day1,T).
dayofTheMonth(Month,Day,T) :-
    Day1 is Day+1,
    dayofTheMonth(Month,Day1,T).
```

Finally you only need to link the predicate `dayOfTheMonth/2` with `dayOfTheMonth/3` by starting - evidently - by day `1`.

```
dayofTheMonth(Month,Events) :-
    dayofTheMonth(Month,1,Events).
```

So the full code reads:

```
day(1,1, 'New Year').
day(2,1, 'The day after the new year').
day(23,1, 'The day i will finally understand this language :)').
day(14,2, 'Valentins day').
day(16,2, 'Family day').
day(22,2, 'hein.. dont now lol').

nday(1,31).
nday(2,28).
nday(3,31).
nday(4,30).
nday(5,31).

dayofTheMonth(Month,Day,[]) :-
    nday(Month,Threshold),
    Day > Threshold,
    !.

dayofTheMonth(Month,Day,[(Day,Event)|T]) :-
    day(Day,Month,Event),
    !,
    Day1 is Day+1,
    dayofTheMonth(Month,Day1,T).
dayofTheMonth(Month,Day,T) :-
    Day1 is Day+1,
    dayofTheMonth(Month,Day1,T).
dayofTheMonth(Month,Events) :-
    dayofTheMonth(Month,1,Events).
```

Comment: apparently Events is undefined

Comment: First one, or the second?

Comment: @ApexPredator: my bad, made a small typo.

Comment: on this call  event(Day,Month,Event), i changed it for dayofthemoth but still doesnt work

Comment: The problem remain here day(Day,Month,Event), day is not a function

Comment: Sorry for bothering you

Comment: @ApexPredator: that's probably because you forgot to add dots at the end of each line and there is a small problem with the quotes in `'Valentin's day'` (tested it on my *Linux* machine).

Comment: Thanks again i seriously worked hours on this question!!